# Fluorescent lamp strands not working properly after rearranging

Tags: high-voltage, lamp, fluorescent-lamp

I salvaged some fluorescent cold-cathode fluorescent tubes from an old computer screen. In the original configuration they worked fine and produced an even light.

[image: the setup]

I made a lamp out of it and for this I had to change the wiring and thus make some wires longer while others stayed roughly the same.

[image: wiring]

Now not all of the four strands illuminate evenly.

[image]

I don't really know the science behind it but I guess that the longer wires have a too high voltage drop.

I'm wondering if and how I can make this work with this current setup. I saw someone making tubes light up by exposing them to an electromagnetic field and also when I touch the tubes the lit up area moves around so maybe there is a clever work around or hack to fully ignite the two weaker tubes.

Comment: Go back to the original setup to check everything returns to how it was.

Comment: There's a high voltage between those wires running to the tubes, and you need to be sure that the insulation on wires you used as extensions can handle that high voltage. It's also possible that your extension wires are too close together resulting in excessive capacitance between them . To check if either of these it contributing to the problem, remove all the long extensions from where you've neatly hot-glued them and separate every wire from every other wire - try to get at least a 1/2" gap between them - and see how it behaves.

Comment: what happens if you reverse the wires on a failing tube?

Comment: Longer wires add capacitive load to the high frequency high voltage output of these transformers. If the load symmetry is no longer given, the tubes receive different and / or too low voltages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the wire length at fault, but the capacitance from the wiring or thetube to nearby surfaces.

The high-frequency current can "leak" from the wire or tube, effectively short-circuiting it, where it touch another tube, wire, or [even a finger](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Py4_7_Df_-w).

Keep all wires far from other surfaces and from each other -- do *not* run them together.

Comment: Seperating the cables did the trick. Also shielding two of the cables helped. But one I had to shield and connect the shield to GND and the other shield I left floating. The two other cables I did not have to shield so I just glued them to the base plate slightly apart. Thanks for your help and check out the result if you want:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HqSs.jpg

Comment: Brilliant! Illuminating! A good use for old parts. BTW, a cold-cathode supply can also power other types of glow tubes, even those with filaments (which don't need power because the high voltage ionizes the gas). Also, "filaments" in English would refer to a thin thread or wire, as in an incandescent lamp or at the *ends* of a conventional fluorescent lamp, so I'd call the lamps you use "cold-cathode fluorescent tubes".

Comment: Thanks, I did update my question accordingly.